# How to use Adjacency matrix to find lagrest strongly Connected Component size

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix

If we have a Adjacency matrix like this:

```
0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This network has 5 subgraphs ,v1 to v5 interconnection ,v6 isolation ,v7/v8 interconnection ,v9 to v10 interconnection ,v11 isolation.

I have the code to find the number of strongly Connected Component:

```
public class Demo{

    static int[] hasFriend;
    static int[][] Matrix;
    static int length;
    static int num = 0;
    public static int findCircleNum(int[][] M) {
        hasFriend = new int[M.length];
        Arrays.fill(hasFriend, -1);
        Matrix = M;
        length = M.length;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (hasFriend[i] == -1) {
                helper(i);
                num++;

            }
        }
        return num;
    }
    
    public static void helper(int i) {
        
        hasFriend[i] = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            
            if (Matrix[i][j] == 1 && i != j && hasFriend[j] == -1) {

                helper(j);
            }
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] matrix = {{0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    int maxSubNumber = findCircleNum(matrix);
    //this output is:  maxSubNumber:5
    System.out.println("maxSubNumber:"+maxSubNumber);
}

}
```

this output is:  maxSubNumber:5

I want to input a Adjacency matrix and output the size of the lagrest strongly Connected Component,in this example the lagrest strongly Connected Component is v1 to v5,have five nodes **so the size is 5**，I hope the output is this size.

How to solve this....

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve your problem before asking a question here. Your current "solution" just returns the length of one side of the matrix. It should be fairly intuitive that you will at least have to iterate over all of the elements.

Comment: Okay,I have edit my question.